# Aspose PDF Add save button in pdf form

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose

As per requirement I have placed the save button in pdf using below code:

```
 switch (setting.DefaultValue.ToLower().Trim())
                {
                    case "print":
                        buttton.OnActivated = new NamedAction(PredefinedAction.File_Print);
                        break;
                    case "save":
                        buttton.OnActivated = new NamedAction(PredefinedAction.File_SaveAs);
                        //buttton.OnActivated = new JavascriptAction("this.saveAs({ cPath:" + path + ", bPromptToOverwrite: false, bCopy:true});");
                        
                        break;
                    case "reset":
                        buttton.OnActivated = new JavascriptAction("this.resetForm();");
                        break;
                }
```

Also add action using `NamedAction(PredefinedAction.File_SaveAs);`
but not able trigger save button when opening pdf using chrome.
In acrobat its working fine(on Save click open dialogue with existing file path and asking for save).
Can someone help how I can do the same while open it in chrome.
Thanks for your help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code snippet which you are using to add button and setting their actions? It would help us in testing the scenario accordingly and address it. Please note that it is recommended to post such issues in the official support forum of Aspose.PDF (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) where they can be properly tracked for resolution. Please create a post there with the requested information and you will be assisted accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your valuable feedback.